# avro schema : add a new enum symbol in a FULL_TRANSITIVE compatible way

Tags: enums, avro

How am I supposed to add a new symbol to the enum in a FULL_TRANSITIVE compatibility mode? Is this impossible ?

I have now :
{
"name": "version",
"type": {
"type": "enum",
"name": "Version",
"symbols": [
"v1_0_0"
]
},
"doc": "The version of the event definition",
"default": "v1_0_0"
}

and I need one more value for version, "v2_0_0"

{
"name": "version",
"type": {
"type": "enum",
"name": "Version",
"symbols": [
"v1_0_0",
"v2_0_0"
]
},
"doc": "The version of the event definition",
"default": "v1_0_0"
}